# How to add dynamic MDC to logs in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, mdc

I'd like to add MDC to log messages that dynamically updates.  A specific example would be adding a variable value to the log messages that updates when the variable updates.  I have attempted to do this with a LoggerAdapter, but the value once set remains static even if the variable in my code is updated.

Here is the CustomAdapter I built to attempt to achieve this:

```
class CustomAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):

    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        for key in sorted(self.extra.keys()):
            msg = '[{0}] {1}'.format(self.extra.get(key), msg)
        return msg, kwargs
```

But if I pass a variable to the CustomAdapter to be prepended to all log messages, it does not update dynamically.

For example, I'd like to prepend the value of the variable x to all log messages, but if x changes, I'd like the new value to be automatically prepended to all log messages after x changes.

How can you add dynamic MDC to log messages in Python3?

Edit:  Answered my own question.  Modify the CustomAdapter to use a function call and pass in a lambda returning the variable you want updated.  So the adapter should be:

```
class CustomAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):

    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        for key in sorted(self.extra.keys()):
            msg = '[{0}] {1}'.format(self.extra.get(key)(), msg)
        return msg, kwargs
```